# Xarray wrong map position

Tags: python, python-xarray

I try to plot a xarray DataArray but the position of an image is unusual. I have tried to sort coords but still does not work. Here is the trial.

```
# Here is sample dataset https://github.com/tuyenhavan/Course_Data/blob/main/MainlandSEA_sand.tif
import rioxarray 
import xarray as xr
# Read dataset
ds=rioxarray.open_rasterio(r"C:\Users\hava_tu\Downloads\MainlandSEA_sand.tif")
# Plot the first band
# ds[0].plot() # Throw errors indicating AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
# Test with sort y and x values 
ds["x"]=sorted(ds.x)
ds["y"]=sorted(ds.y)
# Plot it again
ds[0].plot()  # Throw errors again AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(ds)` so we can see what you’re working with?  And whenever asking about errors please provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I will be more specific next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many geospatial datasets have latitude coordinates in descending order. This is intentional, and xarray can work with data in this format - plotting your variable shouldn’t be a problem.

The built in python method `sorted` always returns a list, and when you assign coordinate values with a list or unlabeled array like this the values will be overwritten, but it won’t change the ordering of the arrays indexed by them, so this is likely where your arrays and dim orders are becoming mid-aligned:

```py
# this results in invalid data - don’t do this
ds["x"]=sorted(ds.x)
ds["y"]=sorted(ds.y)
```

Instead, either don’t worry about this and just work with the data in descending lat order, or use xarray’s [`sortby`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sortby.html) to sort the arrays and coordinates:

```py
ds = ds.sortby("x").sortby("y")
```